# XSD for parsing Visio 2013

Tags: xml, xsd, visio

I am looking for XSD file for Microsoft Visio 2013.

The XSDs for Visio 2003, 2007 and 2010 are available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visio/archive/2011/05/31/visio-2010-xml-schema-definition-released.aspx).

The XSD for Visio 213 is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj684223.aspx).

The 2013 Visio XSD fails while parsing schema.  Please provide an XSD that can be successfully used.

Comment: XSD of the second link uses XSD 1.1. The XSD is a valid XSD 1.1, but probably your parser reports errors claiming that xs:assert or xs:alternative elements are invalid. It seems your parser is old and only supports XSD 1.0; you'll need a parser/validator that support XSD 1.1 such as saxon or xerces.

Comment: @sergioFC is right, but one has to wonder why Microsoft would publish an XSD dependent upon XSD 1.1 when they've long since lost interest in implementing "new" W3C standards such as XSD 1.1 and XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for information sergioFC, but i want to generate JAXB classes by parsing XSD for Visio 2013. I am trying to generate these classes using XJC. Can you throw some light regarding how to generate JAXB classes from the XSD for visio 2013.